# is nvidia GeForce MX330 CUDA enabled?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to run something that requires CUDA and CUDNN. But in the Nvidia page, I didn't see that MX330 is listed as CUDA enabled. I tried a few things to install CUDA but there are some kind of errors. Wonder if someone actually succeeded and if MX330 is CUDA compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The Geforce MX330 is not listed on the official NVIDIA "[CUDA GPUs](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)" or "[CUDA Legacy GPUs](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus)" pages. So, no.